# Repeat Interval Cannot Be Zero

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm working on upgrading Quartz from 1.8.6 to 2.2.1.

In the previous code, we created a trigger like so:

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.makeImmediateTrigger(0, 0);
```

This was valid syntax previously.  However, since Quartz 2, they've moved to a builder-based system instead.  Below is what I thought would accomplish the same thing, however, I get the error `Repeat Interval Cannot Be Zero`.

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
        .withIdentity(getImmediateTriggerName(jobInfo))
        .forJob(job)
        .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
            .withIntervalInMilliseconds(0)
            .withRepeatCount(-1))
        .build();
```

Obviously this isn't working, so I'm wondering what would be the best way to accomplish the same thing that we were doing previously.

Thanks

Comment: How many times should the trigger fire, 0 or 1?  The code above suggests 0, but I can't see the point of creating a trigger that never fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want the trigger to fire only once.

According to the [Quartz 1.8 source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/1.8.0/org/quartz/TriggerUtils.java#TriggerUtils.makeImmediateTrigger%28int%2Clong%29), calling `TriggerUtils.makeImmediateTrigger(0, 0)` creates a `SimpleTrigger` with repeat count 0 and repeat interval 0.  According to a [Quartz 1.8 tutorial](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/TutorialLesson05), example 1, this creates a trigger that fires only once.  This would therefore seem to be what your Quartz 1.8 code is doing.

From the [Quartz 2.2 TriggerBuilder API documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/TriggerBuilder.html):

> [If] you do not invoke *withSchedule(..)* method, a default schedule of firing once immediately will be used.

So, it would seem that all you need to do is to get rid of the `withSchedule` section from your trigger:

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
        .withIdentity(getImmediateTriggerName(jobInfo))
        .forJob(job)
        .build();
```

I appreciate that the Quartz 1.8 documentation isn't entirely clear about repeat count.  The [documentation for the Quartz 2.2 ScheduleBuilder](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/SimpleScheduleBuilder.html#withRepeatCount(int)) is much clearer on this point: the repeat count doesn't include the first firing.  Despite seeing your code attempting to set the repeat count to -1, I can't believe you actually want the trigger to never fire, as [triggers are automatically deleted after they have repeated the required number of times](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html#getRepeatCount()), and it would be pointless to create the trigger only to have it immediately deleted without it ever firing.  In fact, if you set the repeat interval to a positive number of milliseconds and leave the repeat count at -1, [you would get an error about the repeat count being negative](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.0/org/quartz/impl/triggers/SimpleTriggerImpl.java#SimpleTriggerImpl.setRepeatCount%28int%29).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  I must have missed a few points from the 1.8 documentation/tutorial since I didn't see that calling `TriggerUtils.makeImmediateTrigger(0,0)` would create a trigger that fires once.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also start the job with a delay by this trigger

```
Trigger jobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity(jobname, groupName)
            .startAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + startInterval * 1000L) )
            .build();
```

This way trigger acts with a delay, but the job does not repeat

In case delay in start is not needed

```
Trigger jobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity(jobname, groupName)
            .build();
```

will do

Answer (score 0):

**The issue here is very clear**. I was able to conclude this statement after I ran through the same issue and resolved it.

Here is the problem.

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity(getImmediateTriggerName(jobInfo))
    .forJob(job)
    .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
        .withIntervalInMilliseconds(0)
        .withRepeatCount(-1))
    .build();
```

The issue is with **.withIntervalInMilliseconds(0)
            .withRepeatCount(-1)** as you **cannot specify the Interval to zero.** Just use the simpleSchedule() and this will by default trigger it only once.

Use in the following way,

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
        .withIdentity(getImmediateTriggerName(jobInfo))
        .forJob(job)
        .withSchedule(simpleSchedule())
        .build();
```